# Moving a Web User Control to a different namespace

Tags: asp.net, controls, namespaces

Our web application has a control that's set up with a markup, code-behind, and designer file, as so:

Markup

```
<%@ Control Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false"
    Inherits="NewNameSpace.Controls.generic_selector" Codebehind="generic-selector.ascx.vb" %>
```

For some reason, while it worked before when it was in the default namespace, when we moved it to a new namespace we now get a parser error:

> Description: An error occurred during
>   the parsing of a resource required to
>   service this request. Please review
>   the following specific parse error
>   details and modify your source file
>   appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: Could not load
>   type
>   'NewNameSpace.Controls.generic_selector'.

**Addendum**: I did move the markup, the code-behind, and the designer file to the new namespace. Didn't seem to help.

The project still builds correctly. Is there something else we need to do?

---

**Update**:

Taking another look at it this week, here's my guess. When creating a control by default, it goes in to Global.NameOfProject.NameOfControl.

Maybe the new control is now in Global.NameOfProject.NewNameSpace.Controls?

---

**Update:**

The control does appear to partially go in the namespace Global.NameOfProject.NewNameSpace.Controls. The trouble is, it's not clear how to move the whole class over to a new namespace. I've tried various markup changes and none of them seem to stick - only the default namespace seems to work with no hiccups.

So my question remains: How does one move a Web User Control to a different namespace?

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the namespace on the code-behind class as well.

Open the `generic-selector.ascx.vb` file and make sure that the `generic-selector` type is wrapped in the propert namespace like this:

```
Namespace NewNameSpace.Controls
    Class generic-selector

    End Class
End Namspace
```

Answer (score 2):

I hade the same problem I thoug the same as you ony I had inclued my codefile as normal however after reading this blog [aspnet-context-is-not-member-of-user.html](http://jvk-codex.blogspot.com/2009/07/aspnet-context-is-not-member-of-user.html) and change my code file  via the intellisense and it worked. It seems that it needs the relative path

> When creating a custom user control you may encounter an error stating that "Context is not a member of ControlName". There are numerous reasons why this may appear. The most common that I have seen are:
>
> Missing the Namespace in the Inherits property (if you are not using one than this does not apply)
> Missing a CodeFile or the CodeFile path is wrong, you can use the Intellisense to browse for the file to ensure proper pathing

Comment: Lone link is [considered a poor answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) since it is meaningless by itself and target resource is not guaranteed to be alive in the future. [It would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.